# iOS images using Monotouch (Xamarin), Rotated images

Tags: ios, image

I've been looking at this for quite a while and this makes no sense.   I have two possible images A.png that is 28x28, and A@2x.png that is 56x56.

I load the image, and draw it and it is perfect - both normal and retina screens draw the image in the same space, with the retina being better resolution.

the Image objects have the following attributes:

```
Image.Size.Width = 28     or 56 for @2x image.
Image.Width = 28
Image.CurrentScale = 1.0  or 2.0 for @2x image.
```

All well and good.

Now, I want to rotate the image.  I run it through the function I have below, and it comes up with an image with EXACTLY the same attributes as above - a rotated image with 28x28 in the .width and .height, and either 28 or 56 in the image.size.width and with the currentScale set too.

HOWEVER, it draws half the size of the original image on a retina screen!   I have verified that is the case by commenting out the call to this method, and it draws 2X larger.

What is wrong with this code???

```
    public static UIImage RotateImage (UIImage src, float angle)
    {
        UIImage Ret, Tmp;
        float newSide = Math.Max (src.CGImage.Width, src.CGImage.Height);// * src.CurrentScale;
        SizeF size = new SizeF (newSide, newSide);

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (size);
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

        context.TranslateCTM (newSide / 2, newSide / 2);

        context.RotateCTM (angle);
        src.Draw (new PointF (-src.Size.Width / 2, -src.Size.Height / 2));
        Ret = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();        

        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();  // Restore context

        if (src.CurrentScale != 1.0f)
            {
            Tmp = new UIImage (Ret.CGImage, src.CurrentScale, UIImageOrientation.Up);
            Ret.Dispose ();
            return (Tmp);
            }

        return Ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out,  The drawing was drawing 28x28, centered.  Replacing the drawing code makes the image all better.

```
context.RotateCTM (angle);
src.Draw( new RectangleF (-src.CGImage.Width / 2, -src.CGImage.Height / 2, newSide, newSide));

Ret = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
```

The src.Draw line is the one that was changed.